# How can I generate an Entity-Relationship Diagram and SQL DDL statements from natural language text?

Tags: database-design, erd

I am using LaTeX or another text-macro tool/library. How can I (1) use natural language text to describe relationships, then (2) generate an Entity-Relationship Diagram and (3) generate SQL DDL to create the database schema from it?

Comment: What SQL are you trying to generate?  DDL or DML?

Comment: DDL (for Oracle)

Basically just the Create reference + attribute related commands need to be generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but the most important thing to know is that there is a name for what you want to do: [Object Role Modeling](http://www.orm.net/). It's a process for creating conceptual models using natural-language semantics.

[This is a pretty good (if old) overview of the process.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290383%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

The [Wikipedia page for ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Role_Modeling) has a pretty complete list of the available tools, many of which are free.

The most up-to-date solution is [NORMA](http://www.ormfoundation.org/files/10/default.aspx), since it is actively maintained by the [ORM Foundation](http://www.ormfoundation.org/), but that's a plug-in that requires Visual Studio.

If you don't have Visual Studio, [Infagon](http://www.infagon.com/) looks like it is still pretty actively developed and may be your best bet.

[CaseTalk](http://www.casetalk.com/php/index.php?Purchase) is also worth a look. Free to students and educators, but commercial otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think I will write the SQL by hand, and generate a diagram from that using SchemaSpy.

Unless you can think of a quicker; more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this once with a document parser tool I wrote.  It would strip out specially formatted comments from a DDL statement and produce a data dictionary.  This was renedered with LaTeX.  However, I still had to reverse engineer the database into Visio to make E-R diagrams.

For a limited subset of SQL needed to parse create table statements it wasn't too hard to write the parser.  I had it working in a couple of weekends.

Comment: Awesome, would you be able to share this?

Answer (score -2):

Hey If it's any help i have used visio to create my ERD and revere engineer it to DB using it's Reverse engineering tool, which provides reverse engineering support to ms access, ms sql server, ...